# CoreGraphics: Creating a circle with a stroke and a shadow in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, core-graphics

Right now this is how I do it:

```
CGRect handleRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(handleRect.size, false, 0.0);
CGContextRef handleRectContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(handleRectContext, [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f/255.0f green:0.0f/255.0f blue:0.0f/255.0f alpha:0.25f].CGColor);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor([UIColor colorWithRed:255.0f/255.0f green:255.0f/255.0f blue:255.0f/255.0f alpha:1.00f].CGColor);
CGContextSetLineWidth(handleRectContext, 0.5);
CGContextSetShadowWithColor(handleRectContext, CGSizeMake(0, 1), 2.5, [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f/255.0f green:0.0f/255.0f blue:0.0f/255.0f alpha:0.75f].CGColor);
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(handleRectContext, handleRect);
CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(handleRectContext, handleRect);
CGContextFillPath(handleRectContext);
UIImage *circle = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

This creates the circle without the stroke but with a clipped off shadow (clipped at the 20x20 rect). If I remove CGContextSetShadowWithColor the stroke is there but *obviously* the shadow not.

How can I actually create a circle with a stroke and a shadow that's not clipped of and/or blurry?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my current solution (Create a larger rectangle that contains the smaller circle):

```
CGSize handleSize = CGSizeMake(overlayHeight,overlayHeight);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(handleSize, false, 0.0);
CGContextRef handleContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetLineWidth(handleContext, 0.5);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(handleContext, [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f/255.0f green:0.0f/255.0f blue:0.0f/255.0f alpha:0.25f].CGColor);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor([UIColor colorWithRed:255.0f/255.0f green:255.0f/255.0f blue:255.0f/255.0f alpha:1.00f].CGColor);
CGRect circleRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, handleSize.width, handleSize.height );
circleRect = CGRectInset(circleRect, 3, 3);
CGContextSetShadowWithColor(handleContext, CGSizeMake(0, 1), 2.5, [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f/255.0f green:0.0f/255.0f blue:0.0f/255.0f alpha:0.75f].CGColor);
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(handleContext, circleRect);
CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(handleContext, circleRect);
CGContextStrokePath(handleContext);
UIImage *circle = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

If anyone has a better/easier solution please let me know!